# How to access values from NSSet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am using CoreData and it's returning a NSMangedObject. I have taken it into NSSet and now i want to take the value out and display it. Here's the code snippets:

```
NSManagedObject *financialsData = [serverResult valueForKey:@"financials"];
    NSSet *financiers = [financialsData valueForKey:@"planFinanciers"];
    for (NSManagedObject *financier in financiers) 
    {

    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 8):

You haven't told us anything about the attributes and relationships that a particular financier has, but in general you can use accessors or KVC to get the data from each object:

```
NSManagedObject *financialsData = [serverResult valueForKey:@"financials"];
NSSet *financiers = [financialsData valueForKey:@"planFinanciers"];
for (NSManagedObject *financier in financiers) 
{
    // Assuming there are 'name' and 'netWorth' attributes...
    NSLog(@"Name: %@\tNet Worth:%.2f", financier.name, financier.netWorth);

    // ...or...
    NSLog(@"Name: %@\tNet Worth:%.2f", [financier valueForKey:@"name"], [[financier valueForKey@"netWorth"] floatValue]);
}
```

Don't take my word for it, though... read [Managed Object Accessor Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW1).